# Starting kafka on Linux or Win

Tags: apache-kafka

I have tried for the last 10 hours to start the kafka server but I couldn't.

I managed to install zookeeper and run it on win10 but I had the

```
classpath is empty. please build the project first e.g. by running 'gradlew 
 jarall'
```

error.

So I installed ubuntu and the jre 9, zookeeper workd fine here ,too. But kafka does not. The latest error I get is:

```
[0.000s][warning][gc] -Xloggc is deprecated. Will use -Xlog:gc:/home/emi/kafka/bin/../logs/kafkaServer-gc.log instead.
Unrecognized VM option 'PrintGCDateStamps'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I even switched to java 8 and tried different versions of kafka, but I can't get it going. In both cases I don't think it's a problem of environement variables for java since zookeeper works just fine: java -version returns

```
    java version "1.8.0_151"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved on Windows, probabily using the source file instead the scala compiled was the problem